# What is an augmented reality mobile application?

Tags: augmented-reality, mobile-application

I've heard the term "augmented reality" used before, but what does it mean?

In particular, what is an augmented reality iPhone application?

Comment: Isn't that where you stick lots of little models to the outside of your iPhone?

Comment: See also these closely related questions: [Is there a good tutorial for implementing an augmented reality iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084327/is-there-a-good-tutorial-for-implementing-an-augmented-reality-iphone-application) and [How to begin with augmented reality?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604097/how-to-begin-with-augmented-reality)

Answer (score 3):

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality

> Augmented reality (AR) is a term for a
>   live direct or indirect view of a
>   physical, real-world environment whose
>   elements are augmented by virtual
>   computer-generated sensory input, such
>   as sound or graphics. It is related to
>   a more general concept called mediated
>   reality, in which a view of reality is
>   modified (possibly even diminished
>   rather than augmented) by a computer.
>   As a result, the technology functions
>   by enhancing one’s current perception
>   of reality.
>
> In the case of Augmented Reality, the
>   augmentation is conventionally in
>   real-time and in semantic context with
>   environmental elements, such as sports
>   scores on TV during a match. With the
>   help of advanced AR technology (e.g.
>   adding computer vision and object
>   recognition) the information about the
>   surrounding real world of the user
>   becomes interactive and digitally
>   usable. Artificial information about
>   the environment and the objects in it
>   can be stored and retrieved as an
>   information layer on top of the real
>   world view. The term augmented reality
>   is believed to have been coined in
>   1990 by Thomas Caudell, an employee of
>   Boeing at the time.

Incidentally, there are some images at the above URL that should make what's being discussed above fairly evident.

Answer (score 0):

An augmented reality application is software that adds (augments) data or visuals to your experience on your camera.

[image]

Popular examples include snapchat filters, yelp monocle, and various map applications.

[image]

[image]

---

"Augmented reality (AR) is a live direct or indirect view of a physical, real-world environment whose elements are "augmented" by computer-generated or extracted real-world sensory input such as sound, video, graphics or GPS data. It is related to a more general concept called computer-mediated reality, in which a view of reality is modified (possibly even diminished rather than augmented) by a computer. Augmented reality enhances one’s current perception of reality, whereas in contrast, virtual reality replaces the real world with a simulated one.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4Ul6.jpg) Augmentation techniques are typically performed in real time and in semantic context with environmental elements, such as overlaying supplemental information like scores over a live video feed of a sporting event." source: [wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality)