# how application knows that camera is pointed on area

Tags: android, gps, augmented-reality

I'm wondering on one thing. There is a lot of apps for android that allow you to look on the stars and see labels near them or see airplanes with labels and data from public databases. The thing that I want to know is:

How application knows that it is looking on the specific part of the sky or area. Cause I also saw application that can point a building. I understand that there is a database with lat and lng (geo data) but I have no idea how to check from code that I'm looking on the specific part.

I don't want the code, I just need a clue to figure it out

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure but i could give you a pointer . This subject comes under augmented reality . Google Goggles for example is one kind of app you are talking about , this application can tell you all about whats in a picture by using some special algorithms . But , you say you want to know of camera positioning etc.

I've done some research and arrived at a few other stack results:

[How to begin with augmented reality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604097/how-to-begin-with-augmented-reality)

[augmented reality framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939318/augmented-reality-framework)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4797000/3436603

and one non-stack helper website for desert.

http://www.cwjobs.co.uk/careers-advice/it-glossary/the-10-things-you-need-to-know-about-augmented-reality

Happy to help !

EDIT:

here's one more extremely helpful link (library):

https://code.google.com/p/andar/

Comment: you've missunderstood my question. I'm not asking about the AR or for the frameworks etc. I'm looking for the solution how to calculate if the point with geo coordinates is in front of me so I can mark it. I've already have the overlayes etc I'm looking for the alghoritm to check if point with specific coordinates is in sight range of my camera in phone